# Factorial on a list elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have list of lists and the result should be, list of list with the factorial applied to each element.

[[1,2],[3,4],[3],[1,1,1]]=[[1,3],[6,24],[6],[1,1,1]]

code for factorial for one list:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n *factorial (n-1)
fun x = map factorial x
```

Comment: Your question isn’t clear. If you are trying to apply the factorial to each element of each list, why does the last list gain an additional element ([1,1,1] vs [1,1,1,1])? Or is that a typo?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for a plain (non-nested) list?

Comment: There is a typo.

Comment: @bereal Yes, i have updated the question.

Comment: You just need to nest the `map`s

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to apply the `factorial` function to each element of each sublist of the list. Fortunately, it’s a very common pattern in Haskell to map a function over another function. To do that, you use the higher-order function `map`. `map` takes a function and a list and returns a list where every element is the result of the function applied to the corresponding input list’s element.
But what do you do if you want to map it over a nested list? You’d like to map the mapping. This is possible because Haskell allows you to *partially apply* functions. You can omit an argument, and you get a function with the other arguments pre-filled. For instance, if `foo x y = x + y * y`, `foo 2` is a function, too, that takes another value, and the result of `(foo 2) z` is `2 + z * z`. So you can also write `map factorial` without the list at the end to mean the mapping.

And then, the **solution is:**

```hs
factorialsOnNestedList list = map (map factorial) list
```

…but you can η-reduce this to `factorialsOnNestedList = map $ map factorial`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you as you've shown in your question, you know how to find the factorial for every element of a list:

```
fun x = map factorial x
```

(Side note: whenever you have the pattern `function arg = someOtherFunction arg`, you can just write `function = someOtherFunction` - in this case,

```
fun x = map factorial x
```

becomes

```
fun = map factorial
```

)

So if you have a nested list, you want to apply `fun` to every list inside the nested list. What can you use for that? `map` again

```
funNested nestedList = map fun nestedList
-- Or, by removing `nestedList`:
funNested = map fun
```